# Java Library with Keyboard Key Mappings

Tags: java, keyboard, keymapping

This question is almost identical to a previous question ([Keyboard Layout library to find Neighboring Keys given an input key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120646/keyboard-layout-library-to-find-neighboring-keys-given-an-input-key-java-prefer)). However, that question is 5 years old.

Is there a library I can import that will tell me, for a given key *k*, which keys neighbor *k*? I know I can manually create this mapping, but it would be great if something more robust was already out there.

Per Alex's comment, this is for a US English QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: Keyboards are different. Not to talking about different devices, OSes or methods of input (Chrome, Siri, etc).

Comment: I've added clarification